# WP localhost path loads, then resolves to remote

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

I have a remote instance of a previously developed WP site running on my Linode at (e.g.) "site.mydomain.com".

I have a local version running in MAMP Pro. when I drill down into htdocs to my working directory, and hit localhost:8888/site/wp-admin/, the url unexpectedly resolves to http://site.mydomain.com.

As I say, this is a site already developed and deployed which we have back in order to do some @font-face css updating.

Since it's built on a custom theme I had nothing to do with, I'm unaware of what hackiness may have been done that might cause this redirect.

Given the behavior, can anyone suggest where I might look for the directive that would tell WP to load the remote site despite the site being invoked from localhost? I don't believe it's an etc/hosts issue, but I could be wrong. I'm still a bit wet behind the ears.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your wp_options table and adjust the values accordingly.

Comment: done. two records adjusted to point back into localhost.

n.b.- omit the trailing slash in both urls.

Answer (score 1):

From [the wordpress codex:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

> When your domain name or URLs change - i.e. from
>   http://example.com/blog to http://example.com, or http://example.com
>   to http://example.net - there are additional concerns. The files and
>   database can be moved, however references to the old domain name or
>   location will remain in the database, and that can cause issues with
>   links or theme display.

Wordpress has a bad habit of putting full URL's in the database. I think it's been improved since the last time I had to move a site, but reading the referenced page above will probably answer your question.

Comment: I had believed I had done a complete find and replace of URL strings to localize the db. I suppose I could have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you move your site from your localserver to live server.Remeber to change the `URLs` in database.otherwise it will keep pointing to your localurl.

Run these queries:

```
 SELECT * from wp_options where option_name = 'siteurl' 
 SELECT * from wp_options where option_name = 'home'
```

change the  URL in `option_value` to Live server URL.and here you go

Comment: more fire-power than needed, but someone might find those useful.